# How to eliminate duplicates from a list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, hash

```
class infoContact
{ 



    private string contacts_first_nameField;

    private string contacts_middle_nameField;

    private string contacts_last_nameField;        

    private Phonenumber[] phone_numbersField;

    private Emailaddress[] emailField;
}
```

I have a `List<infoContact>` The list contains almost 7000 which I get from some other program. In the list out of 7000, 6500 are duplicates. I am looking for a way how to eliminate duplicates.

A infoContact is duplicate if first_name, last_name, emailaddresses, phone numbers are same.

I thought of using a `HashSet<infoContact>` and override getHashCode() of infoContact.

I am just curious to know if that is the best way to do. If this is not a good way what is the better way?

Comment: Your thought of using a HashSet sounds like a good plan. You'll also need to override Equals in addition to GetHashCode.

Comment: I am almost sure this is a duplicate question. We had it here a few months ago, just go and find it. :-) HashSet<T> was probably the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly think of extracting the unique values. You could use the Distinct() Linq method with a comparer like:

```
public class infoContactComparer : IEqualityComparer<infoContact>
{
    public bool Equals(infoContact x, infoContact y)
    {
        return x.contacts_first_nameField == y.contacts_first_nameField
            && x.contacts_last_nameField == y.contacts_last_nameField
            && ...
    }

    public int GetHashCode(infoContact obj)
    {
        return obj.contacts_first_nameField.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Distinct extension method that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>`. Just write a class that implements that interface, and does the comparison, and then you can just do something like this:

```
var filteredList = oldList.Distinct(new InfoContactComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

override an equals method with the parametres you want so you can compare objects through equals

Answer (score 1):

i created a remove deducted items from list class before here is the key for it ,

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(somefile.txt))
        {
            if (!list.Contains(line))
            {
                list.Add(line);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options: override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` if you control the source of `infoContact` *and* your overrides will be true for any particular use of the class.

Otherwise, define a class implementing `IEqualityComparer<infoContact>`, which also allows you to define proper `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods, and then pass an instance of this into a `HashSet<infoContact>` constructor *or* into a `listOfContacts.Distinct` method call (using Linq).

Note: your question seems to be based on the idea that `GetHashCode` should determine equality or uniqueness. It shouldn't! It's part of the tool that allows a HashSet to do its job, but it is not required to return unique values for unequal instances. The values should be well distributed, but they can ultimately overlap.

In short, two equal instances should have the same hash code, but two instances sharing the same hash code are not necessarily equal. For more on guidelines for `GetHashCode`, [please visit this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Implement your class `infoContact` as a derivate of `IEquatable<infoContact>`:

```
class InfoContact : IEquatable<InfoContact> {
  string contacts_first_nameField;
  string contacts_last_nameField;
  object[] phone_numbersField;
  object[] emailField;
  // other fields

  public bool Equals(InfoContact other) {
    return contacts_first_nameField.Equals(other.contacts_first_nameField)
           && contacts_last_nameField.Equals(other.contacts_last_nameField)
           && phone_numbersField.Equals(other.phone_numbersField)
           && emailField.Equals(other.emailField);
  }
}
```

and use Linqs `Enumerable.Distinct` method in order to filter the duplicates:

```
var infoContacts = GetInfoContacts().Distinct();
```

Comment: I'm not taking this too serious, but also note that you should use UpperCamelCase/Pascal naming for class names as these are by default exposable within the same assembly. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to ovveride the equals method!

In this way, when you add new element in the list, the element don't will be added!

Comment: This is just plain wrong. Lists can happily contain duplicates, and override equals will only help as a fallback to GetHashCode when the items are added to a HashSet (or through a method that uses HashSet)